# How to publish report created in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to know how to publish the report created in python so that user can see? For example whenever I create a report in any other reporting tools (ex: Qlikview. Qliksense, Tableau, Power Bi etc...) I publish them to their respective server and the link gets generated for that report and I will share that particular link to user to see the reports.

So is there any server for python to publish the reports? How in real-time the reports gets published? I created a basic bar graph and i would like to publish the output to user

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
%matplotlib inline

Order = pd.read_excel("Superstore.xls", sheet_name = 'Orders')
Return = pd.read_excel ("Superstore.xls", sheet_name='Returns')
Order["Year"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(Order["Order Date"]).year
result = Order.merge(Return, on='Order ID', how='inner')\
    .groupby(["Year", "Segment"]).agg(Final_Sales=("Sales", sum)).reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))
ax.set_title('Segment and Years Wise Sales')
sns.barplot(x = 'Segment', y = 'Final_Sales', hue = 'Year', data = result)
for p in ax.patches:
             ax.annotate("%.0f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=10, color='black', xytext=(0, 5),
                 textcoords='offset points')
plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: You are confusing software with a programming language.  You can write software in Python that creates graphs and emails/provides some UI for users to see them.  Or I'm sure there is a bunch of libraries/software companies that already do that.  But there in no magic "share my graph with a bunch of users" library in python.

Comment: You have just published your graph. At least, I can see it now…

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: There isn't any library exists like that or at-least not a free ones.
Qlikview. Qliksense, Tableau, Power Bi etc are web-applications developed in web technologies. You might want to google django.

You can save your reports locally first and then upload those reports to some Image uploading server e.g Imgur.

Checkout their API: https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython and https://api.imgur.com/models/image

This is not exactly what you're looking for but it could be work around.

```
saved_img = "path_to_your_generated_graph"

from imgurpython import ImgurClient
client_id = 'YOUR CLIENT ID'
client_secret = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET'

client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret)
upload_from_path(saved_img, config=None, anon=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically what the Datapane Python framework and API does.

```
pip3 install -U datapane
```

```
import datapane as dp

...

dp.Report(
  "Check out my cool report!",
  dp.Plot(fig),
  dp.Table(result),
).publish(name='my_report')
```

You can use the [open source library](https://github.com/datapane/datapane) to create standalone interactive reports from Python visualization libraries, pandas dataframes, files, and markdown.

It currently supports the following libraries (but make an issue if you would like another one added):

- Matplotlib
- Seaborn
- Altair
- Bokeh
- Plotly
- Folium

Additionally, a free hosted platform is provided so you can can publish your reports, share them with others, and embed them into other platforms. You can check out some example things the community is building in [the gallery](https://datapane.com/gallery).

Disclosure: I'm one of the people building Datapane.